# Load Json file Case Insensitive

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I trying to make below code case insensitive but its not working.

If i try to load exact name `!ping george` its workings but if i try to mix upper or lower `!ping George` bot not reply's.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, namesList):
  with open('data.json') as json_file:
    d = json.load(json_file)
    for p in d['people']:
      if(p['Name'] in (namesList)):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, p)
```

I changed this `if(p['Name'] in (list)):`  to   `if(p['Name'].lower() in (list)):`

Still its not working i think i doing mistake in this line.

---

Edit from comment:

```
namesList # from json file names contains  with upper lower mixed.
some names contain numbers, and some names have space between name and sir name.

data.json sample

{"people": [
{"UserID": "xxxxx123", "Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age": "30"},
{"UserID": "xxxxx124", "Name": "Rachel", "Sex": "Female", "age": "25"},
{"UserID": "xxxxx125", "Name": "George", "Sex": "Male", "age": "22"} ] }
```

Comment: You don't tell us what's in `list`. (Which by the way is a very, very [bad name for a variable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html).) Are the names in there all in lowercase as well?

Comment: In list from json file contains names with upper lower mixed some names contain numbers also.

Comment: There's your problem then. How can `p['Name'].lower()` *ever* be found in a mixed-case string?

Comment: So i trying find how to do it work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) of lower-case names and look up your `p["Name"]` in it:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, namesList):
  # sets are better for lookups. prepare a set with all lower case names 
  setOfNamesLowerCase = set ( x.lower() for x in namesList ) # dont name lists list
  with open('data.json') as json_file:
    d = json.load(json_file)
    for p in d['people']:
      if(p['Name'].lower() in setOfNamesLowerCase ):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, p)
```

Sets are better suited for this task, lookup is O(1) and in case you have duplicates they get automatically reduced.

---

Logic reduced to check if it should work, given correct inputs:

```
def find_tata(namesList):
    # sets are better for lookups. prepare a set with all lower case names 
    setOfNamesLowerCase = set ( x.lower() for x in namesList ) # dont name lists list
    if "tata" in setOfNamesLowerCase:
        print("Its in")
    else:
        print ("Its not")


find_tata( ["not in here","not in"])
find_tata( ["not in here","tata"])
```

Output:

```
Its not
Its in
```

---

Edit 2:

```
import json

js = """{"people": [
    {"UserID": "xxxxx123", "Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age": "30"},
    {"UserID": "xxxxx124", "Name": "Rachel", "Sex": "Female", "age": "25"},
    {"UserID": "xxxxx125", "Name": "George", "Sex": "Male", "age": "22"} ] }"""

def ping(namesList):
    # sets are better for lookups. prepare a set with all lower case names
    setOfNamesLowerCase = set ( x.lower() for x in namesList ) # dont name lists list
    d = json.loads(js)
    for p in d['people']:
        if(p['Name'].lower() in setOfNamesLowerCase ):
            print("Doing smth for ", p["Name"]) 

ping(["rachEl", "ludwig", "ernie", "GEoRgE"])
```

Output:

```
Doing smth for  Rachel
Doing smth for  George
```

Comment: now its not working for both correct names or lower upper names.

Comment: @Bosen You should probably debug your values in that case. Most probably either `namesList` or whatever the json gives you as `p["Name"]` is not what you think it is. This might help you out: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I tried your updated code but still bot didn't responded or not even received error code.now its not responding if i type same name exactly.

Comment: @Bosen - if the set contained a name thats stored in your json p.["name"] as string it _would_ work. hence the link. Set a breakpoint and debug the values that you got.  Or do some logging - to console or to a file or whatever. Check your data - the code works. Maybe your assumptions about datatypes are incorrect and your "list" was a dict or your d['people'] is a dict or p['Name'] is one.

Comment: added json sample code in question. if i use my original code and type `!ping Steve`  it works but not works for `!ping steve` and if i use your code both not works.

Comment: @Bosen - see edit. The code as is works - so something that is not set/test related is amiss. anysc / await , the bots context, no idea...

Comment: your edit 2 getting output in bash. no idea y its not working in `await bot.say`